# I Want to make a Pop up window over main window

Tags: python, tkinter, popupwindow

It should behave like that when the pop up is open we cant use main window until we exit the pop up

Reason I dont use tkinter messageboxes because the way i cant customize it

I want to Customize and found a way to do so but problem is when pop up is open then i can easily click the main window buttons and open multiple popups so i want the main window gets disabled when the window pops up and get back to normal when pop-up is closed

My code be like

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
win.title("Main Window")

def closing_try():
    close = Tk()
    close.title("Warning")
    close.geometry('200x100')
    close.overrideredirect(0)
    close.configure(bg='white')
    close.resizable(False, False)
    close.attributes("-topmost", True)
    close.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

    def save_b_func():
        close.destroy()
        save_func()
        win.destroy()

    def dont_save_b_func():
        win.destroy()
        close.destroy()

    def cancel_b_func():
        close.destroy()

    
    ask_lbl = Label(close, text='''Do You Want to Save File
Before Exiting?''', bg='white', font=('consolas', 10, 'normal'))
    ask_lbl.place(x=10, y=5)
    save_b = Button(close, text='Save', font=('consolas', 10, 'normal'), command=save_b_func, bg='white').place(x=9, y=50)
    dont_save_b = Button(close, text="Don't Save", font=('consolas', 10, 'normal'), command=dont_save_b_func, bg='white').place(x=53, y=50)
    cancel_b = Button(close, text='Cancel', font=('consolas', 10, 'normal'), command=cancel_b_func, bg='white').place(x=139, y=50)

    close.mainloop()

button = Button(win, text='click me', command = closing_try).pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want main window to be visible, you can do:

```
win.grab_set() # show popup window
win.grab_release() # return to normal
```

or

```
master.withdraw() # hide main window
master.deiconify()# return main window
```

here is some example code so you can understand how it works:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

win.geometry("450x400")
new_win = Toplevel(win)
new_win.geometry("700x250")
new_win.title("NEW WINDOW")
new_win.withdraw()
Label(new_win, text="Example Label", font=('Helvetica 15 bold')).pack(pady=10)


def show_new():
    new_win.grab_set()
    new_win.deiconify()


def show_old():
    new_win.grab_release()
    new_win.withdraw()


def print_text():
    print("BUTTON IS PRESSED")


button = Button(win, text="Show",command= show_new)
button.pack(pady=50)
button_text = Button(win, text="print",command=print_text)
button_text.pack(pady=100)

button2 = Button(new_win, text="OK",command= show_old)
button2.pack(pady=50)

win.mainloop()
```